# datetime error in extracting the date using php

Tags: php

How can I show this date in the following format.

```
2013-06-14T19:48:05
```

I have used  `$date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");` and I can't get `T` before the time.

`2013-06-14 19:48:05`, this is what I am getting when I run my php script.

Comment: You can't open the PHP docs, find time format, and read about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can format your date like this:

```
$date = date("d-m-Y\TH:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

php has a function for formting date

```
date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

you can allso use flags for well known formats

```
date_format(object,format);
```

List of formats:

1. DATE_ATOM - Atom (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+00:00)
2. DATE_COOKIE - HTTP Cookies (example: Friday, 12-Apr-13 15:52:01 UTC)
3. DATE_ISO8601 - ISO-8601 (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+0000)
4. DATE_RFC822 - RFC 822 (example: Fri, 12 Apr 13 15:52:01 +0000)
5. DATE_RFC850 - RFC 850 (example: Friday, 12-Apr-13 15:52:01 UTC)
6. DATE_RFC1036 - RFC 1036 (example: Fri, 12 Apr 13 15:52:01 +0000)
   7 .DATE_RFC1123 - RFC 1123 (example: Fri, 12 Apr 2013 15:52:01 +0000)
7. DATE_RFC2822 - RFC 2822 (Fri, 12 Apr 2013 15:52:01 +0000)
8. DATE_RFC3339 - Same as DATE_ATOM (since PHP 5.1.3)
9. DATE_RSS - RSS (Fri, 12 Aug 2013 15:52:01 +0000)
10. DATE_W3C - World Wide Web Consortium (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+00:00)